# Java Regex Behavior

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to apply the below pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?");
Matcher m = p.matcher("RAJ");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBufffer();
while(m.find()) {
 m.appendReplacement(sb, "L");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

Expected Output : LLL
Actual output : LRLALJL

Does the Dot(.) in the above regex match the position between the characters? If not why is the above output received

Answer (score 5):

The `.*?` matches any number of characters, but as few as necessary to match the whole regex (the `?` makes the `*` [reluctant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html#difs) (also known as lazy)). Since there's nothing after that in the regex, this will always match the empty string (a.k.a the place *between* characters).

If you want at least a single character to be matched try `.+?`. Note that this is the same as just `.` **if** there's nothing else after it in the regex.

Comment: +1, but I would emphasize that reluctance vs. greediness is not the source of the problem--it just makes the symptoms more interesting. :P  If you were to change the reluctant `.*?` to a greedy `.*` you'd get `LL` as a result, and a greedy `.+` would give you simply `L`.  As you pointed out, `.+?` yields the correct output, but only because it acts like `.`.  The real solution is to get rid of the quantifier, as @rmunoz demonstrated.

Answer (score 3):

You can get it doing this:

```
String s = "RAJ";
s = s.replaceAll(".","L");                                                                                                                                                                                  
System.out.println(s);
```

You can do it using a Matcher and find method, but replaceAll accepts a regex.

Comment: +1 for the only (so far) correct solution (although @Joachim did point out that `.+?` is effectively the same as `.`) and yes, `replaceAll()` (found in the String class as well as well as in Matcher) does the same thing as the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks, it was a simpler approach.

Answer (score 2):

It is not that `.` matches between the characters, but that `*` means 0 or more and the `?` means as few as possible.
So "Zero or more things, and as few of them as possible" will **always** match Zero things, as that is the fewest possible, if it's not followed by something else the expression is looking for.

`.{1}` would result in an output of `LLL` as it matches anything once.

Comment: The `.` alone will match once--or more precisely, it will consume exactly one character.  The `{1}` pseudo-quantifier has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` in your regex `.*?` means none or more repetitions. If you want to match at least a single character use the regex `.+?`.